# Why does React useRoutes giving me invalid hook error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i'm trying to add route on my project but some error happened

```html
import React from "react";
import News from "./NewsComponents/News";
import Photos from "./PhotosComponents/Photos";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Home from "./Home";
import { useRoutes, setBasepath } from "hookrouter";

setBasepath("/");

const routes = {
  "/": () => <Home />,
  "/news": () => <News />,
  "/photos": () => <Photos />,
  "/contact": () => <Contact />,
};

function MainComponent() {
  const page = useRoutes(routes);
  return <div>{page || alert("error")}</div>;
}
export default MainComponent;
```

and happening this error
[hook error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coi4U.png)

**update**
so if problem is not there here are other components

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import MainComponent from "./components/MainComponent";
import { navigate, setBasepath } from "hookrouter";

setBasepath("/");

function App() {
  const [button, setButton] = useState("home");
  const toggle = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "home") {
      setButton("home");
      navigate("/");
    } else if (e.target.id === "news") {
      setButton("news");
      navigate("/news");
    } else if (e.target.id === "photos") {
      setButton("photos");
      navigate("/photos");
    } else if (e.target.id === "contact") {
      setButton("contact");
      navigate("/contact");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header button={button} onClick={toggle} />
      <MainComponent />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and in index.js

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

i cant find where problem is tried everything to solve this but without any result, its working when i'm deleting *const page = useRoutes(routes);*

Comment: what is the react version the app is using? Please check inside the package.json and let me know :)

Comment: Hello, its 17.0.2

Comment: How are you using `MainComponent`? Are you calling it as a regular function? `MainComponent()` Function components should only be used as `<MainComponent />`.

Comment: i'm using as <MainComponent />

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code in there is fine, so I am thinking it's the version mismatch problem.

Set these versions below in package.json.

```
"hookrouter": "^1.2.5",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

Run `npm ci`.

---

If this does not work, try replacing components inside routes with `<div></div>` to see if any of the components is causing problems.

If the above is not case, please check if you are rendering ReactDom correctly in index.js

Comment: everything was correct, but hookrouter was missing in package.json, i write by hand but didnt help, also checking npm ci wrote bunch of errors